# How to associate load balancer with ACL in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-load-balancer, amazon-waf

I read this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/web-acl.html

I read that ACL can be associated with a cloudfront as well as with load balancer.

I could find the tutorial for cloudfront http://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/tutorials-rate-based-blocking.html

But i am unable to find any tutorial for associating ACL with load balancer. Nor i could find any option on AWS console UI for the same.

Any help.

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly the same as the process for CloudFront that you linked. In the WAF console it will list all your CloudFront distributions and load balancers that you can associate the WAF with.

Comment: I have a load balancer. But that is not visible in the dropdown of ACL creation wizard. There are categories.. for Global i have cloudfront only.. And for the rest (eg us-east) there are no any option. what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

Is late, but this might help someone looking for this answer. When you are creating your ACL,on the *Region* section, make sure you select the region of your LB, example: US-EAST virginia instead of the default Global (Cloud Front). Then the dropdown menu will list all your Elastic LB and you can easily select yours.